# Targeting checkboxes within a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table in which I am trying to use jquery to target checkboxes. I want to click a checkbox within an individual td and then change that td's background color, but I can't seem to target the checkboxes at all. this is the tr of my table (it has more td's I just included two for this error.

```
<tr class="sources">
  <td><a href="#">Single Life Annuity</a></td>
  <td>
    <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="relval">100%</span>
      <span class="benyou">$517.00</span>
      <span class="benben">$0</span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="left"><input type="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="relval">98%</span>
      <span class="benyou">$2,916.00</span>
      <span class="benben">$0</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the jquery I am using to find the checkbox's. I am using a console.log to make sure I have found the checkbox but in essence would use `addClass(".active");`

```
 $(".sources td").click(function(e)
 {
   $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
   console.log('you got it!');
 });
```

Any help would be great!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your CSS also.

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: Check the selector you are using...

Comment: FYI:  `click` is not the only event type that will activate a checkbox.  The `change` event is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example (which is bound to clicks on the table cell), this would select the cell and apply a red background to it:

```
$(this).css('background','red');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HLtmt/)**

If you'd rather bind to the click event of the checkbox, try this:

```
$(".sources td input").click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
     $(this).closest('td').css('background','red');
    console.log('you got it!');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HLtmt/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the .prop() method.

```
 $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

As required : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TnL9/2/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background','red');
    } else {
       $(this).parent().parent().css('background','white');
    }
});
```

Other way, works by clicking anywhere in `<td>` : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSEkD/)

```
$(".sources td").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) { 
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).closest('td').css('background','white');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).closest('td').css('background','red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to find the `.closest('td')` instead of finding the parent of the parent?